# In 2.8 how do I drop a modeling tool?

Tags: modeling, shortcut

While I'm modeling in 2.8 I will be using a tool, like the "extrude region" tool.  Is there a key command to drop the tool and be back to the original selection arrow tool?  If I use "b" for box select, I can change my selection, but I'm still in the "extrude" tool.  How can I drop a tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2.8 introduces the "Active tool" system.

From now on, Blender has an active tool that you can choose in the tools menu on the left side of the viewport. There is always an active tool, you just have to switch. It's a different thing than calling a tool like we used to do in previous versions (and is independent of that).

Think of it like the gizmo in 2.7: it's always here, you use it or not, you can switch between location, rotation, and scale. The active tool system is basically the same thing, but with extra tools added.

Comment: Ok, that is a fine explanation.  If the tool stays active, I just need to figure out a shortcut to get back to the original selection arrow.  "B" goes to box select, which isn't what I want to go to.  Is there a shortcut for the select arrow?

Comment: Calling a tool doesn't change the ACTIVE tool, it really is two different things. If you want to get the same behavior as in 2.79, set the active tool to Move tool and don't touch the active tools bar.
For the shortcuts, it's simple. Using Left Click Select and Playback Spacebar: call the Active tool menu via Shift Spacebar, then use the indicated shortcut for the tool you wish).

Answer (score 2):

There is always one tool active so closest option to exiting tool is to switch to Select Box.

For shortcut:
You can press first 'Escape' key to cancel if in middle of operation and then 'W' key *once* to switch out of current tool like extrude/inset etc. to Box select tool.
Pressing 'W' second time or more will change the select option from box to circle and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Simply press Esc to get out of a tool in edit mode.

Comment: That was my worry.  I use a newer MacBook Pro with the digital Esc key, no physical button.  Hopefully they will eventually recognize that as a key stroke.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

In the top left where it shows your tools you can click a new one. I'm assuming you want a selection tool since you mention the box select. You can click and hold on any of the tool boxes to open up a drop down to select a different tool. one of them should be the default tool you're looking for.